# Jquery stop calculation using this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make some calculations between inputs , I have 7 inputs and what I want to do is making calculations between them , so this is my code

```
      $('.empCosts').on('input', function () {
        var perHour = parseInt($('#per_hour').val());
        var hours = parseInt($('#hour').val());
        var perDay = parseInt($('#per_day').val());
        var days = parseInt($('#day').val());
        var perMonth = parseInt($('#per_month').val());
        var month = parseInt($('#months').val());
        var perYear = parseInt($('#per_year').val());
        var perdayVal = parseInt(perHour * hours);
        var perMonthVal = parseInt(perDay * days);
        var perYearVal = parseInt(perMonth * month);
        var perHourVal = parseInt(perDay / hours);
        var perMonthDivide = parseInt(perYearVal / month);

        $("#per_day").val(perdayVal);
        $("#per_month").val(perMonthVal);
        $("#per_year").val(perYearVal);
        $("#per_hour").val(perHourVal);
        if($(this).is(":focus")){
            alert('sdfasdfad');
        }
    });
```

these inputs should be connected either you multiply or divide , when I try to change per_day value it doesn't change because I already set the value of that input with var `perdayVal = parseInt(perHour * hours);`, I want either you increase the number or decrease it , it should make the calculation either multiplying or dividing the inputs, here you have the fiddle

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2jb2e3Lv/)

Comment: You need to add some if's to see which input is changing and do your calculation based on that, if you don't know how to do that, then just bind separate calculations to to each input rather than just trying to do one massive calculation - it would make more sense to do that anyway as certain inputs only affect certain results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/2jb2e3Lv/7/

```
$('.empCosts').on('input', function () {
    var perHour = parseInt($('#per_hour').val());
    var hours = parseInt($('#hour').val());
    var perDay = parseInt($('#per_day').val());
    var days = parseInt($('#day').val());
    var perMonth = parseInt($('#per_month').val());
    var month = parseInt($('#months').val());
    var perYear = parseInt($('#per_year').val());
    var perdayVal = perHour * hours;
    var perMonthVal = perDay * days;
    var perYearVal = perMonth * month;


    $(this).attr("id") !== "per_day" && $("#per_day").val(perdayVal);
    $(this).attr("id") !== "per_month" && $("#per_month").val(perMonthVal);
    $(this).attr("id") !== "per_year" && $("#per_year").val(perYearVal);
});
```

Comment: ok, and how to use divison also, if i change per year it should change the per month input also

Comment: did you mean this https://jsfiddle.net/2jb2e3Lv/12/

Comment: yes thank you you cann add this to answer